# How can I use SVN functions within PHP?

Tags: php, svn

I'm a new to SVN and trying to manipulate it through PHP.  I tried using popen() to execute SVN calls directly to no avail.

I found [this module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) on php.net which has methods to manage SVN within PHP.

So, how do I install and configure this module?

Comment: I had no idea php had this.. I'm very interested to know too

Comment: Well, you might want to be more precise what "this problem" actually is. If you got specific questions about the SVN API, please refine your question to name them.

Comment: The documentation on php.net is indeed far from perfect, but it should be possible to master this challenge. If can handle svn, then you should be able to handle this API.

Comment: this question is not very clear... what do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 5):

If you use Ubuntu (or maybe another Debian-based OS), you can install this very easily by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-svn
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If it installed and Apache restarted smoothly, you should be able to use any of the SVN functions listed in PHP's docs!

To get you started, here's a PHP script which updates the repo in the current directory

```
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_USERNAME, 'yourUserName');
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_PASSWORD, 'yourPassword');
$b4 = trim(`svnversion`);
if ($revision = svn_update(realpath(getcwd()))) { //use @svn_update(...) if you want to hide warnings
    if ($b4 === trim(`svnversion`)) {
        echo 'Already up-to-date (r'.$b4.').';
    } else {
        echo 'Updated to r'.$revision;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Update failed';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you working on?  SVN will work the same no matter what language you are working with.  Just find the a good tool for your platform.

**Windows**

- [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) - One of the best SVN tool kits around.

If you are asking about how to control and SVN respoitory from PHP then you should just read up on the docs.  I found a more detailed manual on [doc.php.net](http://doc.php.net/php/dochowto/svn-checkout.php)

Comment: i'm very noob, and i don't know how to install and config libsvn to php :(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/svn.installation.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.pear.php

On *nix, try `pecl install svn` on the command line.

If PECL doesn't work, try `yum install php-devel`

Answer (score 0):

... on CentOS 7.0 one can install it like that:

install prerequisites:

```
yum install php-devel subversion-devel php-pear
```

download php-svn and build it:

```
pecl install svn
```

add the config file:

```
echo "extension=svn.so" > /etc/php.d/svn.ini
```

restart HTTPd:

```
/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
```